# How to identify Subset in SQL join

Tags: sql

I want to identify subset group when joining two tables.

I want to identify which ProductGroup order was placed, criteria is all option , value combinations from Order should match from Product Options group. [in other terms all order rows for a order should be subset of Product group ]

Product option table.

```
ProductKey| Option   | Value  | Group
PRD-A     | Shape    | Square |  1
PRA-A     | Color    | Blue   |  1
PRA-A     | Color    | Red    |  1  
PRD-A     | Round    | Square |  2
PRA-A     | Color    | Pink   |  2
```

Order table

```
OrderNo | ProductKey | Option | Value
ABCD    | PRD-A      | Shape  | Square
ABCD    | PRD-A      | Color  | Blue
```

I'm joining on ProductKey, Option and Value.

I'm expecting.

```
ProductKey| Option   | Value  | Group
PRD-A     | Shape    | Square |  1
PRA-A     | Color    | Blue   |  1
```

but currently I'm getting group 2 records as well.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I'm joining on ProductKey, Option and Value.` what is the whole query? And what is the output?

Comment: @manishparab . . . What is this `ABCD    | PRD-A      | Color  | Blue` supposed to be matching to?

Comment: Your expectations include  PRA-A     | Color    | Red .   My expectations do not include that row of output.  Why do you expect it?  It was not in the order.

Comment: agree, @donPablo, but how can I avoid the "PRD-A     | Round    | Square |  2" coming in result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the expected result, you will have to join tables with Option and Value only.

```
select p.* from Product p
inner join Order o
on  p.option = o.option
and p.value= o.value
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select p.ProductKey, p.option,p.value,p.group
 from product p , order o
 where p.ProductKey=o.ProductKey
 and p.option=o.option
 and p.value=o.value
 ;
```

Comment: From group 2 -- but ONLY if ProductOptionTable was not unique on ProductKey / Option / Value.  If Key/Option/Value is duplicated in more than one Group, then there is no way to prevent multiple rows. However, when KKL-s sql is used, and when no dupes are present, then all should be fine.